# query all data from 2 postgres tables using node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am querying all the data from a single table in a schema called data in postgres using the following node code :

```
const getperson = (request, response) => {
  db.query('SELECT * FROM data.person', (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error
    }
    response.status(200).json(results.rows)
  })

app.get('/person', getperson)
```

This schema also contains other tables, I would also like to get data from those tables, put together and displayed when someone lands on /getall.

I tried changing the query to this `SELECT * FROM data.person JOIN data.animal`, but it returned nothing.

Or this `SELECT * FROM data.person, data.animal`, but this returned only the results of uncommon objects in the table, for example if the id of data.person was 1 and data.animal was 1 it would only return the id of one of the two.

Comment: You really want *ALL* the data? If so, you'll need to create a select / table

Comment: @Xavier, yes all the data, I just want it to spit out everything in both the tables.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is probably to make several `SELECT * FROM table` and handle it with Node…
However, if all the queries returns the same number of columns, then you can use `UNION` like:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name_1
UNION
SELECT * FROM tbl_name_2
...
```

Comment: They do not have the same number of columns.

Comment: Then go for plan A :)

Comment: The whole reason for this question was because I do not know how to do that.

Comment: Just copy/paste what you got for `getperson` and use it for `getanimals`, `get…` and return all the data

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to concatenate the queries:

```
const getAll = (request, response) => {
  db.query('SELECT * FROM data.person;SELECT * FROM data.animal', (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }
    response.status(200).json({people: data[0].rows, animals: data[1].rows});
  })

app.get('/all', getAll);
```

Comment: How does this work? When running multiple statements, the results become an array with `node-postgres`?

Comment: @Bergi `node-postgres` swaps `Result` with an array of `Result`-s when more than one result-set is returned.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know! Doesn't seem to be documented anywhere though.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are many things missing in that library's documentation. And I've tried my best to make up for that from within `pg-promise` documentation.